# Splitting string into smaller strings

Tags: c#, string, foreach, split

I have a following list of names:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
names.Add("Tom Example");
names.Add("Ron Example");
names.Add("Peter Pavel Example");
names.Add("Pavel Ron Tom Example");
```

I want to split string in smaller strings for each element of list:

```
string firstName;
string firstInitial;
string lastName;
string lastInitial;
string secondName;
string secondInitial;
```

I want do this method in loop becouse I want to do some things on that small strings. And if I have 3 names and surname in string I want to have only first and second name and surname. For clearance:

For last element of list I want to have that result:

```
string firstName == Pavel;
string firstInitial == P;
string lastName == Example;
string lastInitial == E;
string secondName == Ron;
string secondInitial == R;
```

I have no idea how to implement this problem to work correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: How can you reliably say that the second string is not a surname, but initial ?

Comment: Count how many words are in the string(To see if he has two firstnames or only one), split them, use sub-string for the split-ed strings and you're done.

Comment: I take strings from database so always surname is the last world.

Comment: Do you mean these are separate strings in the database? if so then you are much better off parsing them straight from the database

Comment: Have a look at `Split`, `Count` and `First` ?doesn't seem you have an issue really ...

Comment: In database i have one string. But if someone have 2 surnames there is "Example-Example" in string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've prepared following solution for yourself:

```
public enum NameOptions
{
    FirstName = 1,
    MiddleName = 2,
    LastName = 4
};
```

Then extensions:

```
public static string SafeTokenPosition(this string @string, int index)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(@string))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    var tokens = @string.Split(new[] { " " }, 
                               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    return index >= tokens.Length ? string.Empty : tokens[index];
}

private static string ResolveLastName(string name)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    var tokens = name.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    switch (tokens.Length)
    {
        case 2:
            return tokens[1];
        case 3:
            return tokens[2];
        default:
            return string.Empty;
    }
}

private static string ResolveMiddleName(string name)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    var tokens = name.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    switch (tokens.Length)
    {
        // ex. John Pablo Kowalsky
        case 3:
            return tokens[1];
        default:
            return string.Empty;
    }
}

private static string ResolveFirstName(string name)
{
    return name.SafeTokenPosition(0);
}
```

And final extensions:

```
public static string ExtractName(this string @string, NameOptions nameOptions)
{

    switch (nameOptions)
    {
        case NameOptions.FirstName:
            return ResolveFirstName(@string);
        case NameOptions.MiddleName:
            return ResolveMiddleName(@string);
        case NameOptions.LastName:
            return ResolveLastName(@string);
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException("Name " + nameOptions + " is not supported.");
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var firstName = "John Sample".ExtractName(NameOptions.FirstName);
```

It should be easily to extend to handle initial letters and two - seconds names.

Comment: "name.SafeTokenPosition(0)" string does not contain a definition.
"Condition.Requiers(...)" Condition does not exixt in current context.

Comment: I first time try tokens so I need time to learn to tokens. So sorry for my slow answers.

Comment: Just remove that line.  Its external library for nullity check. You can write simple if.

Comment: SafeTokenPosition(name, 0) - this is correct i think.
And ExtractName("John Sample", NameOptions.FirstName);

Comment: Okey I correct errors and the method works perfect! Thanks man! You know maybe some good websites from where I can learn tokens?

Comment: @Sowiarz my code works - that are method called `Extension` methods: http://www.dotnetperls.com/extension It's not working for you because you have probably imported namespaces not properly or class that holds method is not static class.